# Waiting for values from unknown children component number before effet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Assuming there is a parent component:

```js
function Parent({ children }) {
  useEffet(() => {
    // Do something when all children 
    // have returned their values via props (or context)
  })
  return <div>{ children }</div>
}
```

How can I run effect *only after* **all** children have done something? I don't know the exact number of children and it can vary:

```js
// In this example there are 4 children
function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Children />
      <Children />
      <Children />
      <div>
        <Children />
      </div>
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

The actual problem is that all children can prepare a query (let's say an ElasticSearch Query), and the parent is responsible to actually perform the whole query.

Comment: Control props? you pass a `prepareQuery={(query) => /* set parent's state, push in an array or whatever */}` prop to every children, and let them call that function internally. `Parent` should be aware of the number of children rendered, so it's just a matter of counting how many children did call their `prepareQuery`, and run the effect only at that point.

Comment: > "Parent should be aware of the number of children rendered"
How could it be aware? Children number is unknown (see example) and could be nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we could wrap the action the Children does into a Promise:

```
  function usePromises() {
    const promises = useMemo([], []);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => { // this gets deferred after the initialization of all childrens, therefore all promises were created already
          Promise.all(promises).then(setResult);
     }, []);


    function usePromise() {
      return useMemo(() => {
       let resolve;
       promises.push(new Promise(r => resolve = r));
       return resolve;
      }, []);
    }

   return [result, usePromise];
}
```

Now create one shared manager (inside of the Parent):

```
  const [queries, useQueryArrived] = usePromises();
  // queries is either undefined or an array of queries, if all queries arrived this component will rerender
  console.log(queries);
```

Then pass down `useQueryArrived` to the children and use it there (inside the Children):

```
  const queryArrived = useQueryArrived();

  // somewhen:
  queryArrived({ some: "props" });
```

Now the logic goes as follows:

The Parent gets rendered for the first time, it will create the `promises` array. The childrens will get initialized and each of them creates a Promise that gets attached to `promises` the Promise's resolver gets memoized so that the same resolver will be returned on every child rerender. When all children were initialized, React renders and the effect gets fired, which will take all the promises and call `Promise.all` on them.

Now somewhen `queryArrived` gets called in the children, the promises resolve, somewhen the last promise resolved, which then call `setResult` with all the promises results which will cause a rerender on the Parent, that can now use the queries.

Comment: You should not be able to call `useEffect` inside a callback. ( or any hooks )

Comment: I'm not doing that.

Comment: `useEffect`'s inside `isDone`. `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` lint should be able to catch the issue.

Comment: That's indeed an interesting solution. My example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4omm31729

Comment: @JonasWilms I tried your code but it runs into "nextCreate is not a function": https://gist.github.com/rap2hpoutre/0c0bdc8eca54b7973677b35abdf7dea5

Comment: @rap-2-h "Then pass down useQueryArrived to the children"

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a `finish` state when all children finished *"doing something"*.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const totalChildren = React.Children.count(children);
    if (totalChildren === finish) {
      console.log("All Children Done Something");
      setFinished(0);
    }
  }, [finish]);
```

For [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2vz1l7ky5r?fontsize=14):

```js
function Children({ num, onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{num}</button>;
}
function Parent({ finish, setFinished, children }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const totalChildren = React.Children.count(children);
    if (totalChildren === finish) {
      console.log("All Children Done Something");
      setFinished(0);
    }
  }, [finish]);
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [finish, setFinished] = useState(0);

  const onClick = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
    setFinished(finish + 1);
  };
  return (
    <Parent finish={finish} setFinished={setFinished}>
      <Children num={num} onClick={onClick} />
      <Children num={num + 1} onClick={onClick} />
      <Children num={num + 2} onClick={onClick} />
      <div>
        <Children num={num + 3} onClick={onClick} />
      </div>
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

Furthermore, you can use `React.cloneElement` and add *"updating finish state"* functionality to your children components.